# How to adjust HTML elements using org-publish in Emacs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, org-publish

I am attempting to use org-publish for site generation, and want to alter the html elements currently being exported.

Using `#+INCLUDE` statements within the org files doesn't allow for the markup I am after, so I think the best approach is to adjust the `:html-preamble` and `:html-postamble` arguments within the `org-publish-project-alist` variable.

When including `:html-preamble` and `:html-postamble` properties the default markup exported goes something like this:

```
<div id="preamble" class="status">...</div>
<div id="content" class="content">...</div>
<div id="postamble" class="status">...</div>
```

however I want to change the divs to a more semantic markup such as this:

```
<header id="preamble">...</header>
<main id="content">...</main>
<footer id="postamble">...</footer>
```

I thought this could be acheived by setting the `:html-divs` property like so:

```
:html-divs '((preamble "header" "preamble")
             (content "main" "content")
             (postamble "footer" "postamble"))
```

but this results in:

```
<nil id="nil" class="status">...</nil>
<nil id="nil" class="content">...</nil>
<nil id="nil" class="status">...</nil>
```

I have no idea why and could do with some pointers here.

To look over my code visit the project on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/baaash/org2web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not quote property values inside the (quasi-)quoted form that you set `org-publish-project-alist` to! That's too much quoting.

Try:

```el
...
:html-divs ((preamble "header" "preamble")
            (content "main" "content")
            (postamble "footer" "postamble"))
...
```

You've already (quasi-)quoted the whole value. If you quote the inner value, all you are doing is wrapping it in a `quote` form:

```el
:html-divs (quote ((preamble "header" "preamble")
                   (content "main" "content")
                   (postamble "footer" "postamble")))
```

which stays there because of the outer (quasi-)quote, so the value is a list of two things: the symbol `quote` and a list of three lists. The code however expects it to be a list of three lists: chaos ensues :-)

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote as I am new to this site, but thank you sir.  That is exactly the solution.  You're awesome!

Comment: Glad it helped!